# Unable to get the count from an observable in angular 4 with @ngrx/effects@4.1.1 and @ngrx/store@4.1.1

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am trying to insert an element to a database via an effect from a page. Upon clicking the submit the page redirects to a dashboard page where i show the count of those many elements added to the database for a user. 
But after redirect is successful (meaning once the element is created successfully) i am not able to see the count, instead i can see only after refresh.
please follow the screen

[This is the creation page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoSlG.png)

[After clicking on the submit button I should be seeing the count as 4 but i see nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j6p0.png)

[After refreshing the page i can see the count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6bpb.png)

In the create page, after clicking on the createbutton following code is invoked

```
    this._store.dispatch(new SomeAction.AddNewAction( this.somemodel ));
    this._router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
```

in the dashboard constructor

```
    this._store.dispatch(new SomeAction.LoadModelAction(userid));

    this.modelObserver$ = this._store.select('models');
```

In dashboard.component.html page

```
   <div class="text-right">
       <span class="badge badge-secondary">You have {{ (modelObserver$ | async).length }} model</span>
   </div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `LoadModelAction` is loading record from API/database. I'm not sure if dispatching the action in constructor is a good idea.

Firstly: Even if you want to do it, you should dispatch it in `ngOnInit` method.

Secondly: You are not to sure that if you call this action, the records already exist.

If you are using ngrx-effects, solution is simple: you should call dispatching LoadModelAction after succesfully execution of `AddNewAction` Action. That's mean that you should have minimum 3 actions: `AddNewAction`, `AddNewSuccessAction` and `LoadModelAction`. The best solution is if API return your model as a response for adding new element (In this case you need only `AddNewAction` and `AddNewSuccessAction`). If you have some problems with understanding it: share your effects code and I will try to explain it step by step :)